# Subscribe to user changes with Okta/Azure AD/Auth0

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, auth0, okta, google-identity

We are currently implementing feature on our server to allow our B2B customers to connect their own SSO method. So we will automatically register a user if he doesn't have any account.

But we will have to watch if the given user is deleted from the customer group. Is there any way to set a web hook on our side, to receive events from that customer's SSO, in order to be aware of a user deletion (or any other kind of edit that requires the user's token revocation) ?

Otherwise, I know we'll have to periodically send the given refresh token to the provider, so that we know that we can still trust the user existence from the customer's list. But if there's any other way to check that, we will look into it

Comment: Yes, with Azure AD You can subscribe to all different Create, Update, Delete events on the users using Microsoft Graph API. Have a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions